# RegEx for not matching a sequence in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell, regex-lookarounds

I want to validate a string and the regex should not match when a dot "." has a "-" or "_" directly before or after it.

I assume a negative lookahead would be the best approach but I can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this regex based upon **[lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)** which would reject matching a dot which is either preceded by `_` or `-` or followed by `_` or `-`

```
^.*(?<![-_])\.(?![-_]).*$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8zqRrv/1/)**

Powershell,

```
PS C:\Users\user> $reg = "^.*(?<![-_])\.(?![-_]).*$"
PS C:\Users\user> $str = "aaa . aaa"
PS C:\Users\user>
PS C:\Users\user> $str -match $reg
True

PS C:\Users\user> $reg = "^.*(?<![-_])\.(?![-_]).*$"
PS C:\Users\user> $str = "aaa ._ aaa"
PS C:\Users\user>
PS C:\Users\user> $str -match $reg
False
```

Comment: "^(smtp:|SMTP:)?(?!.*\.\.)(?=[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-_.]{2,63}\@)[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]{1,}[a-zA-Z0-9]+@(?!\.)(?=.*\.)(?=[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-.]{1,253}$)[a-z0-9-.]{4,}[a-z]{2,}$"

That is the current RegEx for SMTP validation, I want to avoid the below formats:
john@doe-.com
john@doe.-com
While allowing:
john@doe-enterprises.com

Comment: @Glenn: That's a little complex regex. Are you having some issue with it?

Comment: it's a ugly RegEx I scrapped together to validate SMTP addresses, it seems to work although it's probably horribly written. What I want now is to disallow sequence of "-." or ".-" in the domain part.

Comment: @Glenn: Sure, that's easy. You just need to add this negative look ahead `(?!.*(?:-\.|\.-))` in your current regex after `@` to reject strings if it finds any occurrence of `-.` or `.-` in the string. [Check this demo](https://regex101.com/r/11lHbR/1/) Let me know if you need anything else further.

Comment: That works beautifully, do you see any ways of improving or shortening the RegEx? The last thing I'm struggling with is to limit the amount of "." used in the domain part.

Comment: @Glenn: Sure, I can remove avoidable things and make it as compact as possible.

Comment: @Glenn: I've shortened your regex by removing some unneeded lookaheads. [Check this](https://regex101.com/r/11lHbR/2/) But still it can be improved further because I feel it has too many negative lookaheads which can be combined and made better. If you can give me the rules for accepting a match and rejecting a match with sample data. I can come up with a precise and concise regex that you need.

Comment: My current validation list contains refers to corporate addresses, I'd rather not share them here so I'll need to adapt it first. Is there another way I can share it in a secure manner with you?

Comment: I'll suggest to remove all the sensitive information with some equivalent characters preserving the format and then you can contact me on my skype id `pkr555`

Comment: If I wanted to limit the amount of times the "." occurs in the domain part, how would I do that?

Comment: @Glenn: It is quite easy. You just need to place this `(?!(?:.+\.){3})` negative lookahead just after `@` in the regex which will reject emails that have 3 or more dots in the email after domain part. Generally there are not more than two dots after domain, hence I have chosen this value as `3` but you can change this value and play with the regex.  I've added some sample emails at last in your regex101 url. [Check this](https://regex101.com/r/5LQ2Iv/4)

Answer (score 2):

You do not necessarily need a lookaround,
directly using a negated character class will do also:

```
$RE = [regex]'.*[^_-]\.[^_-].*'

@"
foo.bar
foo_.bar
foo._bar
foo-.bar
foo.-bar
"@ -split '\r?\n' | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -match $RE){
        "{0} matches `$RE" -f $_
    } else {
        "{0} doesn't match `$RE" -f $_
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
foo.bar matches $RE
foo_.bar doesn't match $RE
foo._bar doesn't match $RE
foo-.bar doesn't match $RE
foo.-bar doesn't match $RE
```

Comment: This will enforce the minimum string length to be at least 3 characters due to which it won't match `a.` where as it should as dot is not followed or preceded by `_` or `-`

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi That's a good point. So it depends on OPs unknown use case if my RE is applicable or not.

Comment: Negative lookaheads are good in these kind of situations as they don't require the presence of more characters (unlike positive look ahead or simply other characters) and instead just say, what shouldn't be there and it helps in keeping the valid string length minimal.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi I use them quite often myself and do reference the very same site links :D